# Rails 5 form field to custom params

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

I have a class Reservation in which I want to put a collection (HABTM) of Resources, through an intermidiate class of ReservedResources. This is not a classic HABTM as in ReservedResources I want to store the quantity of the resource reserved.

On the form I want to display the available resources dynamically, something like this:

```
    <% @resources.each do |r| %>
        <%= f.label "#{r.name}" %>
        <%= f.number_field "reserved_resources#{r.id}".intern %><br>
    <% end %>
```

The problem is that there is no method named "reserved_resourcesXX", where XX is the resource ID. I want to store the quantity of the resource per its ID on the params hash, but I can't manage to do that...

Is it possible? If so, how? I want to avoid JS for this...

Comment: isn't it a normal HABTM relationship where you add an extra field quantity?

Comment: Yeah, basically. I did my own middle table to relate the two models, probably decause of my inexperience with rails

Comment: Is intern an attribute of `@resources`?

Comment: intern is to convert that string into a symbol, which the form does not recognize as a method or field of Reservation. I want that symbol to only exist on the params hash

Comment: Any particular reason why you want to store the quantity of resources reserved? Is it not possible to simply do resource.reservations.count?

Answer (score 0):

I'll just start off with an example which I guess will get you going.

**Scenario**

Imagine a store selling products. Users can reserve products to later buy them. They can also define how many of each product they want to reserve.

```
class User
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :products, through: :reservations
end

class Product
  has_many :reservations
  has_many :users, through: :reservations
end

class Reservation
  belongs_to :user
  belongs_to :product
end
```

Now when creating your reservations model you can simply add an extra field `quantity`, resulting in this reservations schema:

```
create_table "reservations" do |t|
  t.integer  "user_id",
  t.integer  "product_id",
  t.integer  "quantity",
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
end
```

So you take a basic HABTM relationship and add the extra field. Thats exactly what HABTM is for, to add extra info when it is required.

**Your usecase**

Adapt this to your models and I assume the html forms will be kinda straightforward from there on.

Comment: I already have something like that:

class Reservation
  has_many :reserved_resources
end

class Resources
  has_many :reserved_resources
end

class ReservedResource
  belongs_to :reservation
  belongs_to :resource
end

However, I want to add a resource to the reservation form from a collection of previously defined resources, in a specific quantity for each resource. That is what is giving the error, as the resource name cannot be used as the field identifier.

Comment: then please rephrase your question, I cannot figure out what you are trying to achieve exactly

Comment: Ok. A Business has employees (User) and resources. To manage my business I want to create a reservation (through a form). On that reservation I want to list the available resources that I can allocate to the reservation I'm creating, with a number field. Since the resources are inserted into the business by a given employee I'm having trouble listing them

...
  <% @resources.each do |r| %>
            <%= f.label "#{r.name} (#{r.current_quantity})" %>
            <%= f.number_field as: "reserved_resources#{r.id}".intern %><br>
        <% end %>
        <%= f.submit %>

Comment: update your question, not comments... new people will read the question and should not have to read through comments to understand what you are trying to do

Answer (score 0):

Actually what you should have is something like:

```
class Reservation < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reserved_resources
  has_many :resources, through: :reserved_resources
end

class Resource < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :reserved_resources
  has_many :reservations, through: :reserved_resources
end

class ReservedResource < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :reservation
  belongs_to :resource
end
```

Now assuming you have `reserved_quantity` attribute in `reserved_resources` table.

Example of use from rails console:

```
resource = Resource.create(name: 'resource 1')
reservation = Reservation.create(name: 'reservation 1')
resource.reserved_resources.create(reservation: reservation, resource_quantity: 20)

reservation = Reservation.create(name: 'reservation 2')
resource.reserved_resources.create(reservation: reservation, resource_quantity: 10)
```

Sanity check:

```
resource.reservations.count
=> 2
```

you can then get total quantity of reserved resources for a particular resource by doing:

```
resource.reserved_resources.sum(:resource_quantity)
 => 30
```

Comment: That's right, but now I need, for a reservation, to have a form that presents all available resources so that the user chooses which to add, and that's the difficult part... How can I do a form like that?

Comment: I think you need to edit your original question and make it a little clearer as to what you are trying to achieve and a bit more information on what you currently have - meaning the relevant parts from your models, controller and form. I suspect you will need to use accepts_nested_attributes and modify your strong params as well as the form.